# Correctly setting up CRS systems for the NUTS (Eurostat) geographies and Doogal's data?

Tags: polygon, r, coordinate-system, point-in-polygon

I'm interested in undertaking spatial matching in R with use of the **[sp](/questions/tagged/sp)** package on some of the publicly available data consisting of:

- *Polygons:* [Nomenclature of territorial units for statistics](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/nuts/overview)
- *X/Y coordinates:* sourced from [Doogal's website,](https://www.doogal.co.uk/PostcodeDownloads.php) with *Easting* values being assigned to `x` and *Northing* to `y`.

## Problem

The challenge seems to be with setting up the correct CRS for both of those data sets.

### *Illustration*

I've initially attempted to set up projections to those discussed [here](https://rpubs.com/adam_dennett/8955), via:

```
shpNUTS <- spTransform(
  shpNUTS,
  CRSobj = CRS(
    "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"
  )
)
proj4string(pointsDta) <- proj4string(shpNUTS)
res <- over(pointsDta, shpNUTS)
```

results in an unusable map:

[image: unusable polygons]

Similarly, the attempt to remove projection via:

```
proj4string(shpNUTS) <- CRS(as.character(NA))
```

Does not improve the map.

#### Matching

The matching is undertaken in a simple manner,

```
sp::over(pointsDta, sp::geometry(shpNUTS))
```

but I've also tried:

```
res2 <- spatialEco::point.in.poly(as(pointsDta, "SpatialPointsDataFrame"), shpNUTS)
```

The matching does not return overlapping points; this is obviously wrong as `x/y` coordinates sourced from Doogal'swebsite reflect UK postcodes so all of the postcodes should be matched against a set of UK NUTS geographies.

---

## Remaining code

The **[shapefile](/questions/tagged/shapefile)** is read via the `readOGR` function available through **[rgdal](/questions/tagged/rgdal)** package, Doogal's data is read via `readCSV` in R. Remaining code reflects basic transformations:

```
pointsDta <- doogalDta[, c("x", "y")]
pointsDta <- na.omit(pointsDta)
coordinates(pointsDta) <- ~ x + y
# reproject nuts
shpNUTS <- spTransform(
  shpNUTS,
  CRSobj = CRS(
    "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs"
  )
)

proj4string(pointsDta) <- proj4string(shpNUTS)
res <- over(pointsDta, shpNUTS)
```

---

## Update

*Updates in reply to provided comments.*

### *Shapefiles*

Concering the shapefiles, I've sourced [this file,](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/geodatafiles/NUTS_2013_01M_SH.zip) that is made available through the [Eurostat website](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts#nuts13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without seeing the shapefile data but I guess that both your datasets will most likely use WGS84 as CRS. At least the X/Y coordinates use that.

So maybe if you assign

```
wgs84_crs = CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
proj4string(pointsDta) <- wgs84_crs
```

it could solve your problem.

If not, then you need to figure out what CRS the layer `shpNUTS` uses, assign the correct CRS and then you can use `spTransform()` to transform it to the same CRS as `pointsDta` layer.

Comment: If the point data is Eastings/Northings then the CRS is [British National Grid](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/osgb-1936-british-national-grid/)

Comment: Well, the dataset provides both Latitude/Longitude and  Eastings/Northings coordinates. I used Latitude/Longitude as it is easier to estimate the CRS for those coordinates.

Comment: Thanks very much for showing interest in my post, I will try those projections today. I was actually trying to find what NUTS uses but it's not clear. I came across [this page](https://data.gov.uk/harvest/gemini-object/6660908e-9519-49b2-9902-ff7d9561d806) that mentions `urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::27700` as used coordinate system.