# Confirming accuracy of spatial match?

Tags: shapefile, r, coordinate-system, sp

As a follow up to [Correctly setting up CRS systems for the NUTS (Eurostat) geographies and Doogal's data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/219646/45300) I have spatially matched a set of files, one with `lat/long` coordinates for postcodes sourced from [Doogal's website.](https://www.doogal.co.uk) The `over` function available through the [**`sp`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/index.html) in **[r](/questions/tagged/r)** package seems to generating plausible results. After assigining **[crs](/questions/tagged/crs)** somehow arbitrarily I'm interested in *verifying that the obtained spatial match is accurate.*

**Are there any methods I could employ to ensure that the obtained spatial match is error-free?**

## Reproducible example

```
# Download ----------------------------------------------------------------

if (!dir.exists("NUTS_2013_01M_SH")) {
    tmpzip <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip", pattern = "estat")
    download.file(url = "http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/geodatafiles/NUTS_2013_01M_SH.zip",
                  destfile = tmpzip)
}
if (!dir.exists("NUTS_2013_01M_SH")) {
    unzip(zipfile = tmpzip,
          overwrite = TRUE,
          exdir = getwd())

}

# Import ------------------------------------------------------------------

shpsEurs <- maptools::readShapePoly(fn = file.path(getwd(),
                                                   "NUTS_2013_01M_SH",
                                                   "data",
                                                   "NUTS_RG_01M_2013"),
                                    verbose = TRUE)

# Projections -------------------------------------------------------------

# Create projections
wgs84_crs <- sp::CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
## Assign
sp::proj4string(shpsEurs) <- wgs84_crs

# Source PCs --------------------------------------------------------------

if (!file.exists("Scotland postcodes.csv")) {
    download.file(url = "https://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodesCSV.ashx?country=Scotland",
                  destfile = "Scotland postcodes.csv")
}

dtaPCS <- read.csv("Scotland postcodes.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

sp::coordinates(dtaPCS) <- ~Longitude+Latitude
sp::proj4string(dtaPCS) <- wgs84_crs

# Match -------------------------------------------------------------------

res1 <- sp::over(x = dtaPCS,
                 y = shpsEurs)
```

### *Results*

```
>> head(res1)
  NUTS_ID STAT_LEVL_ SHAPE_AREA SHAPE_LEN
1     UKM          1   11.62568  127.5792
2     UKM          1   11.62568  127.5792
3     UKM          1   11.62568  127.5792
4     UKM          1   11.62568  127.5792
5     UKM          1   11.62568  127.5792
6     UKM          1   11.62568  127.5792
```